# What approach better for POJO (fields formatting logic)?

Tags: java, android, class, getter, pojo

I'm working with JSON. So I have following POJO classes `Position`, `Person`.
Where `Person` my needed class.

I need to receive formatted values of fields only of `Person` (I'm using only this class, `Position` it's class accroding my JSON strucutre)

Where better implement formatting logic in `Position` or `Person`?

**1st variant, formatting logic in `Position class`**

```
public Position {
    private String value;


    public String getFormattedValue() {
        //Value formatting...
        return value;
}

public Person {
    private Position position;
    ..other fields

    public String getFormattedValue() {
        return position.getFormattedValue();
    }
}

//using 
String neededFormattedValue = new Person().getFormattedValue();
```

**2nd variant, formatting logic in `Person class`**

```
public Position {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
}

public Person {
    private Position position;
    ..other fields

    public String getFormattedValue() {
        String value = position.getValue()
        //Value formatting...
        return value;
    }
}

//using 
String neededFormattedValue = new Person().getFormattedValue();
```

Comment: if the formatting only related to position, i.e. got nothing to do with person's other properties, I would choose first approach.. so no matter it is a person or robot you will get same formatted position.

Comment: for fun only: to be more "java" way, it is better to define an interface call PositonFormatter, and it expose a formatPositionToString method, then create positionFormatter property in both class, define getter and setter. And use the formatter to format the position value. Furthermore you can have a PositionFormatterFactory to produce different formatters based on etc etc configurations..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have second variant, as you Position class should not have formatting logic. 
The second one is more loosely coupled.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having problems converting between JSON, POJO and XML.

So it seems best to use the exact name for get / set, albeit the first character - which is always capitalized.

Eg. If the fields use correct formatting, Android Studio usually suggests the methods(functions) names.  Where the class contains `private String value;`, when you begin typing `public get...` AS should provide you a list.  The correct syntax for the get method would be `public getValue() ...`.

```
public class abc()
{
  private String value;
  private int some_id_of_a_record;
  private String anotherString;

  public String getValue()
  {...}

  public int getSome_id_of_a_record()
  {...}

  public String getAnotherString()
  {...}
```

...
    }

Comment: I think we have misunderstanding. Question not about getters naming, it's about where better to implement value formatting logic, in `Position class` or `Person class`